# Turn off "You're presenting to everyone" Windows notifications during Google Meet screen sharing

Tags: windows, google-chrome, notifications, google-workspace, google-meet

Whenever I present my screen during a Google Meet meeting, I get a notification in my Windows 10 notification center with the following message:

> **You're presenting to everyone.** Click here to return to the video call when you're ready to stop presenting.

[image: Windows notification with title "You're presenting to everyone"]

This would be fine if it only popped up once when I start presenting. However, every time I switch focus between the screen I am presenting and the screen on my other monitor, the notification is triggered again.

How can I avoid having this notification pop up multiple times per meeting when I am using both screens but only sharing one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable notifications specifically for Google Meet via the Chrome notification settings `chrome://settings/content/notifications`.

Under *"Customised behaviours"*, add `https://meet.google.com:443` to the *"Not allowed to send notifications"* list.

If it's already in the *"Allowed to send notifications"* list, click the `⋮` and select `Block`.

[image: Chrome notification settings]

This will block all notifications from Google Meet in Chrome but I couldn't think of any others it sends anyway.